# Two objects seem to share the same address

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates

I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Preview, Windows 7.

I'm using CRTP to be able to conveniently push objects of any type into a seperate vector.

The results are quite strange, however. You'll see I have two classes, `A` and `B` which derive from `Container`. With `T* PushOne()` a new instance is pushed into a static vector and it's address is returned for use.

For some reason, the first instantiated object of class `A` and the first of class `B` seem to share the same address, though.

Here's the code:

```
template <typename T>
class Container{
public:
    static std::vector<T> elements;

    static T* PushOne(){
        //Push a new T object into the vector
        elements.push_back( T{} );
        //Print out its address
        std::cout << "Make " << typeid(T).name() << " at " << &elements[elements.size() - 1] << "\n";
        //Return its address.
        return &elements[elements.size() - 1];
    }
};

template <typename T> 
std::vector<T> Container<T>::elements;

class A : public Container<A>{
};

class B : public Container<B>{
};

int main(int argc, char** args){
    std::cout << "First addresses:\n";

    //a and c are assigned the address
    auto a = Container<A>::PushOne();
    auto b = Container<A>::PushOne(); //Problem gone if this is commented
    auto c = Container<B>::PushOne();

    std::cout << "\nLater addresses:\n";
    std::cout   << &Container<A>::elements[0] << "\n" 
                << &Container<A>::elements[1] << "\n" 
                << &Container<B>::elements[0] << "\n";

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Output from one run on my machine:

```
First addresses:
Make class A at 00700350
Make class A at 006FA929
Make class B at 00700350

Later addresses:
006FA928
006FA929
00700350
```

As you can see, the first and last entry (which are stored in variables `a` and `b` respectively) print the same address at first.

When I print the addresses a second time I get a different result for the first A*.

I always get the same result unless I comment out the line `auto b = ...`. If I do that, `a` and `b` are assigned different addresses.

Comment: Maybe the second `push_back/PushOne` leads to a reallocate on your std::vector<A> to grow it, so that now the first A element is no longer located at 00700350 ? I would check all addresses afterwards.

Edit: Your Later addresses confirms this

Comment: @Matthias247 Guess you're right, the problem disappears if I `reserve` before use, to prevent reallocation. Make an answer if you'd like me to accept it. First come, first serve ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second push_back/PushOne leads to a reallocate on your `std::vector<A>` to grow it, so that now the first A element is no longer located at `00700350`.

Your `Later addresses` printout confirms this.

Answer (score 3):

When you push elements onto a vector, eventually it will need to allocate new memory, and free up the old memory (which other allocations may use).  So, apparently, when you pushed back the second time for  `Container<A>`, a reallocation happened.  Then, when you pushed `Container<B>`, its vector used the memory that the other vector (of `Container<A>`) released.  This is perfectly alright.